# How does PHP detect object scope from function?

Tags: php, scope, private

Right now I'm trying this code:

```
class A {

    private function foo($a) { echo "sent: $a" . PHP_EOL; }
    public function clorch() {
        call_user_func(array($this, "foo"), "clorch");
        call_user_func_array(array($this, "foo"), array("clorch"));
    }

}

$a = new A();
$a->clorch(); //works
call_user_func_array(array($a, "foo"), array("clorch")); //fails
```

Explanation: `call_user_func_array` (or `call_user_func`) in the last line fails because the method which is tried to access is a private method in class A.

But, inside a method (of the same class), calling `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` works as expected (not breaking, because we're in the object's context).

Question: How is that done (regarding internals)?. How does PHP know, from a built-in function's scope, whether it should fail or not (i.e. whether the `call_user_func[_array]` function is being invoked in an object's context)?

Comment: Are you asking how PHP blocks you from accessing private methods from outside a class?  Why do you want to know this?

Comment: no, i'm asking how does php allow it.

Comment: I'm curious bc i saw it in many framweorks and tested by myself. call_user_func_array can access private methods when it was called from inside a method on the same class. Just wanting to know: how that is done?

Comment: If I actually wanted to violate privacy, and not knowing this, I'd use reflection. But I don't wanna break privacy scope, but just know how is this done in an external, built-in, function.

Comment: `call_user_func(array($this, "foo"), "clorch")` is the same as `$this->foo('clorch');`.  My guess is it translates the call from one to the other.

Comment: So, call_user_func is not a function but a language construct?

Comment: Here's the C source for the function.  https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdbf467d2e8b8ac8b9fe0844aeda854aacf28fe2/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4725  It's a function, not a language construct.  I have no idea how it works, so I just kinda guessed.

Comment: Are you trying to make a PHP extension?  Or are you jut curious about how it works?

Comment: And here for the check to see if its private method https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/Zend/zend_API.c#L2980

Comment: Suggestion: stop naming everything `a` or `A`. There are plenty of other letters of the alphabet that are just waiting to make your example code more easily understandable.